# て form of adjective in 'no matter how much' clause

Tags: grammar, て-form

My story book says this:

> どんなに寒いでも...
>
> No matter how cold it is ...

but my grammar book says this:

> どんなに寒くても...

Both of them seem reasonable to me. Are they both correct? Is there any difference in nuance between them? Could I also translate the first sentence (or indeed the second) as "Even if it is so cold..."? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どんなに寒くても...(No matter how cold it is...) is correct, but どんなに寒いでも is incorrect. Maybe it was a typo of どんなに寒い日でも or something.

---

You form the phrase this way:

with i-adjectives: 「どんなに/どれほど+連用形(～く)+て+も」
eg. 「どんなに忙しくても」「どんなに古くても」

with na-adjectives: 「どんなに/どれほど+連用形(～で)+も」
eg. 「どんなにきれいでも」「どんなに好きでも」

with nouns: 「どんなに/どれほど+(adjective)+noun+で+も」
eg. 「どんなにきれいな花でも」「どんなに忙しい人でも」

Comment: Is this an example of an ongoing change (eg でも becoming the more general-use form of this conjunction), or is this just a straight-up mistake?

Comment: @Sjiveru どんなに寒**いでも** is a genuine typo/mistake.