# Validity of て-form of i-adjectives + も

Tags: grammar, i-adjectives, particle-も

I already know of the construction that takes the て-form of a verb + も and means "even if". But can this construction also be used with i-adjectives? For example, would saying the following be correct?

> 高くてもそのレストランに行きたいです。
>   I want to go to that restaurant, even if it's expensive.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24443/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it also works with na-adjectives and nouns.

> 蛇{へび}でも買いたい。
>   I want to buy it, even if it were a snake.
>
> 静{しず}かでも勉強できない。
>   I am unable to study, even if it were quiet.